VB.net published application detected as VIRUS by Windows Defender and removed
I published a VB.net application recently, which works well on my machine, but when I want to install it on any other machine, The Windows Defender app detects my app as a virus and deletes its files. I tried to sign the app update app information or check it on debug or release mode but nothing changed.
I found lots of forums about it on the web but no one reached a clear response for this matter.

I ran into the same issue, my Kasperskey detects VHO:Trojan.MSIL.Cryptos.gen , after I googled it, I found that, Kasperskey needs to update their database to not mark it as a Virus, I excluded it manualy as a workaround

Nag Microsoft about it - they will eventually deal with the false positive. Don't expect an answer though:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission
Anti-virus programs are not an exact science. They rely on loads of AI-type heuristics which lead to many false positives.

Which a programmer/sysadmin should do for all false positives and all AV vendors that falsely report a file: report them to the AV vendor and let them fix it. You help all other programmers/sysadmins that way.

You might need to code-sign the application. In an enterprise environment your internal CA can issue a code-signing certificate. Otherwise you might need to purchase a code-signing certificate from a public CA.

could you explain more about it, please? what's the internal CA? can I make it by myself?

A CA is a Certificate Authority that issues encryption certificates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority If you have a network system administrator they can help. You can also create self-signed certificates, but these are limited
